# How to connect several spinboxes with only one connect-command?

Tags: pyqt, signals-slots

I have several QDoubleSpinBoxes and I want connect them to one Slot. It is possible to make one connect-command, for more than one object? for exampe, I want to connect:

```
doubleSpinBox_1
doubleSpinBox_2
```

to my function "bla". Is there any command like:

```
self."doubleSpinBox_1 **AND** _2".valueChanged.connect(self.bla)
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for spin_id in range(1,3):
  spinboxes = self.findChildren(QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox, "doubleSpinBox_%d"%spin_id)
  if spinboxes:
    spinboxes[0].valueChanged.connect(self.bla)
```

But this code is useful if you have many spinboxes to connect ;)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use `getattr`:

```
for id in range(1,3):
    spinbox = getattr(self, "doubleSpinBox_{}".format(id))
    spinbox.valueChanged.connect(self.mySlot)
```